# How to create a web crawler with Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-crawler

I just recently got interested in how search engines work, and I found out that they use "bots" or "webcrawlers". I immediately started wondering about how do these things work and I wanted to create one! So, first of: how do you make a program that requests a page from a server? It would be awesome if you gave me a simple example in JavaScript (I'm running it as a normal scripting language using Node). Next, is there a Node module that let's me interpret HTML? Create a DOM for me so I can cycle trough all the links and so on? Correct me if I'm wrong but I guess it's done like that... Any examples in C++, C or Python are warmly welcomed as well, although I'd prefer JS or Python because I'm more familiar with high-level scripting languages.

Comment: this might be of interest.. https://github.com/cgiffard/node-simplecrawler

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Getting HTTP pages: [node http.get](http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.1/api/http.html#http.get) (example is there)
- DOM documents: [jsdom](https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom) (also includes examples)

Comment: Thanks! This is just what I was looking for, now, just one more thing: how can I combine those two? Load a page with http.get, and then feed it to jsdom?

Comment: Ok, great, but what do I feed it and how? The "res" object? To jsdom.env?

Comment: Almost correct - instead of feeding the `res` object you should feed it the data. I recommend experimenting a little. I have never used any of this myself.